# Is it possible to introspect into the scope of a Scalar at runtime?

Tags: raku, introspection, rakudo

If I have the following variables

```
my $a    = 0;
my $*b   = 1;
state $c = 2;
our $d   = 3;
```

I can easily determine that `$*b` is dynamic but `$a` is not with the following code

```
say $a.VAR.dynamic;
say $*b.VAR.dynamic;
```

Is there any way to similarly determine that `$c` is a state variable and `$d` is a package-scoped variable?  (I know that I could do so with a `will` trait on each variable declaration, but I'm hopping there is a way that doesn't require annotating every declaration.  Maybe something with ::(...) interpolation?)

Comment: While I'm doubtful there will ever be a runtime way to determine this, it is the kind of thing that the ongoing work on RakuAST will make easily possible to find out at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Elizabeth Mattijsen correctly noted, it is currently not possible to see whether a variable is a `state` variable at run time.  ... at least *technically* at runtime.

However, as Jonathan Worthington's comment implies, it *is* possible to check this at compile time.  And, absent deep meta-programming shenanigans, whether a variable is a `state` variable is immutable after compile-time.  And, of course, it's possible to make note of some info at compile time and then use it at runtime.

Thus, it's possible to know, at runtime, whether a variable is a `state` one with (compile-time) code along the following lines, which provides a `list-state-vars` trait that lists all the `state` variables in a function:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Sub \f, :$list-state-vars) {
    use nqp;
    given f.^attributes.first({.name eq '@!compstuff'}).get_value(f)[0] {
       say .list[0].list.grep({try .decl ~~ 'statevar'}).map({.name});
    }
};
```

This code is obviously pretty fragile/dependent on the Rakudo implementation details of QAST.  Hopefully this will be much easier with RAST, but this basic approach is already workable and, in the meantime, this [guide to QAST hacking](https://github.com/Raku/CCR/blob/main/Remaster/Zoffix%20Znet/Raku-Core-Hacking-QASTalicious.md) is a helpful resource for this sort of meta programming.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of the package-scoped variable, not too hard:

```
our $foo = 'bar';
say $foo.VAR.name ∈ OUR::.keys
```

where we're using the [`OUR` pseudopackage](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages). However, there's no such thing as a `STATE` pseudopackage. They obviously show up in the `LEXICAL` pseudopackage, but I can't find a way to check if they're a state variable or not. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, there is no way to recognize a `state` variable.  Like any lexical, it lives in the lexpad.  The only thing different about it, is that it effectively has code generated to do the initialization the first time the scope is entered.